# Getting wrong results with using AVX instructions and -O3 compiling option

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, avx

I wrote very simple program with AVX instructions, but I am getting different results when I compile the code with -O3 option and -O1 options of g++ compiler, this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int d = 120;
    __m256i r = _mm256_set1_epi32(d);
    int * p = (int *) &r;

    printf("r[0]: %d, ",p[0]);
    printf("r[1]: %d, ",p[1]);
    printf("r[2]: %d, ",p[2]);
    printf("r[3]: %d, ",p[3]);
    printf("r[4]: %d, ",p[4]);
    printf("r[5]: %d, ",p[5]);
    printf("r[6]: %d, ",p[6]);
    printf("r[7]: %d \n",p[7]);                    

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output when I compile with these options (g++ test1.c -o test1 -m64 -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -mavx):

r[0]: 0, r[1]: 0, r[2]: 4195520, r[3]: 0, r[4]: -1880829792, r[5]: 32767, r[6]: 0, r[7]: 0

And this is the output when I compile with these options (g++ test1.c -o test1 -m64 -O1 -ffast-math -march=native -mavx):

r[0]: 120, r[1]: 120, r[2]: 120, r[3]: 120, r[4]: 120, r[5]: 120, r[6]: 120, r[7]: 120

The second results (-O1) is correct, but the first is wrong. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Poke in the dark: Does `-fno-strict-aliasing` fix the problem? Your code violates strict-alising, but it shouldn't matter since SSE/AVX types are declared with `may_alias`.

Comment: No repro with clang. Which g++ version do you have?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issues (`gcc 4.9.2`).

Comment: Thanks guys... the -fno-strict-aliasing solved my problem.

Comment: @user3687068 -- post that as a self-answer and I'll upvote it :) (or if you can't, just let me know here and I'll make it community wiki)

Comment: @Mysticial: I don't think so, I can't find a version of `avxintrin.h` where `__m256i` would be `typedef`-d with `may_alias`.

Comment: @Mysticial: For the record, `__m256i` *is* a `may_alias` type.  That means it can point at anything, *but not the reverse*.  An `int *` has to point at an `int` object, or at anonymous memory that's only been accessed with `int*` and  `char*` or other may_alias types.  [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605).  It's also not well-defined to point an `int*` at a struct of `char` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read your comment saying you already fixed the problem, but on the search engine it still shows up as "no answer", which is a bit misleading to people with similar issues. The original answer that was here was actually wrong, but the original poster hasn't changed the accepted answer to the right one yet, so I'll update this one.

The short answer is that casting `&r` to `(int*)` has no defined behaviour. Refer to galinette's answer for more details.

The defined behaviour way to do this is to explicitly write the register to memory:

```
int[8] p;
_mm256_storeu_si128((__m256i*)p, r);
```

Comment: “multiple pointers point to the same location in memory” is not the description of the strict aliasing rules that programs get miscompiled when they infringe. Anyone interested in the actual rules should read 6.5:6 and 6.5:7 in the C11 standard.

Answer (score 6):

**Disabling strict aliasing will reduce performance in your whole program!**

Casting `&r` to `(int*)` has no defined behavior. `__m256i r` is an AVX register intrinsic and is not necessarily mapped to memory. By getting a pointer onto it, you force the compiler to write it to memory, and by chance it may end up being mapped to a int[8] vector.

It may work with some compilers, with some options, and under some circumstances. However, you should not use this in your code as it may stop working with no warning.

The "defined behavior" way is:

```
int[8] p;
_mm256_storeu_si128((__m256i*)p, r);
printf("r[0]: %d, ",p[0]);
printf("r[1]: %d, ",p[1]);
printf("r[2]: %d, ",p[2]);
printf("r[3]: %d, ",p[3]);
printf("r[4]: %d, ",p[4]);
printf("r[5]: %d, ",p[5]);
printf("r[6]: %d, ",p[6]);
printf("r[7]: %d \n",p[7]);
```

Then you explicitely write the register to memory. This will do the same, but will always work regardless of compiler options. And since disabling strict aliasing will lower the overall code optimization, your whole program will even run faster.